# PHPStorm how to create new branch without new project?

Tags: svn, phpstorm

I am working with PHPStorm 7.1.3 and SVN as version control system.

Since my current project grows, I want to start working with branches and I am wondering whats the easiest way to do this.
Right now my checked out project consists only of the trunk. To create new branches I tried out a little bit and came up with creating a new branch in SVN and then create a new project in PHPStorm to check out the branch. This works as expected, but leads to a lot of projects which I find quite annoying.

So I tried to create a project consisting of the complete SVN repository, like trunk + repositories. But even with correct settings of trunk and repository location, I can not merge the trunk to a branch or vice versa, I always get

> Merge start wasn't found

What do I have to do to create a properly working branch in a project consisting of the whole svn repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check out the whole repository into a single project, so that the project root is a parent for your trunk and branches? The only way to make metging with branches work for such project is configuring vcs mappings for trunk and each of the branches separately, so that you will have not a single working copy, but several ones, and then configure branches for each of them separately and merge using 'merge from'

Actually, having the whole repository in a single project doesn't look like a good idea to me - you will likely have problems with types resolving/navigation because of duplicate stuff + problems using version control + performance issues because of the project size.